# How to implement programmatic menu with panelmenu and defaultmenumodel

Tags: java, primefaces, menuitem, submenu

I tried to implements programmatic `panelmenu` using `defaultmenumodel` and `panelmenu` with PrimeFaces 4.0. The problem is when I implement a simple model, one or more submenus that contains one o more menuitems runs ok. But when I implement submenus that contains menuitmes and more submenus that containts another menuitems, the `defaultmenumodel` not shows all levels.

```
Menu level one
...MenuItem one.one *
...MenuItem one.two *
...SubMenu one.one
......MenuItem one.one.one
......MenuItem one.one.two
...SubMenu one.two
......MenuItem one.two.one
Menu lebel two
... And so on
```

The MenuItem with * not shown when page is rendered
How can I implement these model of menu using DefaultMenuModel and  ??
I want to use pojo to save the menu structure in DataBase for managing.
Thanks

(Added / Edited)
I have run next code suggested but not work using p:panelMenu. With p:menuBAr works well showing an Item and a SubMenu with item inside.

```
//create the first menu item It is not SubMenu, It's a simple MenuItem
//This item not shows in <p:panelmenu>
DefaultMenuItem accueil = new DefaultMenuItem();
accueil.setStyleClass("only simple menuItem");
accueil.setUrl("/accueil.jsf");
this.menumodel.addElement(accueil);

//This work properly ans shows in <p:panelMenu>
DefaultSubMenu submenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
submenu.setIcon(null);
submenu.setLabel("submenu 01");
this.menumodel.addElement(submenu);
//Add items to submenu
DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
item.setValue("Administrar Usuarios");
item.setUrl("/clientapp/modules/admin/manage_users.xhtml");
submenu.addElement(item);
```

Answer (score 3):

I create my menu like this :

Bean:

```
private MenuModel menumodel = new DefaultMenuModel();

//create the first menu item
DefaultMenuItem accueil = new DefaultMenuItem("Accueil");
accueil.setStyleClass("accueil");
accueil.setUrl("/accueil.jsf");
this.menumodel.addElement(accueil);
//Start here i create submenu with personal access for all user
for (Autorisation auto : this.permList) {
    if (auto.getRessource().getSousMenu() != null) {
        if (auto.getRessource().getSousMenu().size() != 0) {
            //Create submenu
            DefaultSubMenu submenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
            submenu.setIcon(null);
            submenu.setLabel(auto.getRessource().getMenu());
            this.menumodel.addElement(submenu);
            for (Ressource r : auto.getRessource().getSousMenu()) {
                //Feed submenu with menu item
                DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
                item.setValue(r.getMenu());
                item.setUrl(r.getPath());
                submenu.addElement(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XHTML :

```
<p:menubar model="#{SessionUser.menumodel}"/>
```

Comment: I think it's good solution I'll try with <p:panelMenu /> Have you tried with <p:panelMenu /> ?

Comment: I have just tu run the code and it work well with <p:menuBar/> but not with <p:panelMenu/> the first item named "accueil" shows in menubar but not shows in panelmenu. Any suggestion?? It's a bug in panelMenu?

Comment: You have to create your own menuitem and add it to the menumodel

Comment: I have edited cuestion to add the code that not work. I create one menuitem and add to menumodel, next create submenu with one menuitem and add to menumodel, finally asign menumodel to p:panelmenu, but not show ther first menuitem. I'm novice with jsf and primefaces and have not experience working with it.

Answer (score 1):

I respond myself.

To use menumodel you need a submenu that wraps (or contains) all menuitems or submenus with their own menuitems.

1. Create `Menumodel`.
2. Create Submenu `mySubmenu`.
3. Create one or more `Menuitems` and then add them to `mySubmenu`.
4. Create one or more `Submenu` objects (that can contains `Menuitems`
   itself) an add to `mySubMenu`.
5. finally add `mySubmenu` that contains all `MenuItem` and `Submenu` items to
   `Menumodel` that created initially.

**Thanks Lamq**, you help me to active my main. (And sorry for my english ::)

Comment: Think to edit your answer for posting a code sample and validate this one that can help some else. You're welcome.